# Find all occurences of a pattern in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file which looks like this

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1
Host is up (0.023s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5001/tcp closed commplex-link
MAC Address: EC:1A:59:A2:84:80 (Belkin International)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.2
Host is up (0.053s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5001/tcp closed commplex-link
MAC Address: 94:35:0A:F0:47:C2 (Samsung Electronics Co.)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.3  
Host is up (0.18s latency).  
PORT     STATE    SERVICE  
5001/tcp filtered commplex-link  
MAC Address: 00:13:CE:C0:E5:F3 (Intel Corporate)  

Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.6
Host is up (0.062s latency).
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5001/tcp closed commplex-link
MAC Address: 90:21:55:7D:53:4F (HTC)
```

I want to find all the IPs with port 5001 closed (not filtered). I tried to use the following logic to find all such IPs

```
fp = open('nmap_op.txt').read()
ip = re.compile('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)(.*)closed',re.S)
matched = ip.findall(fp)
for item in matched:
  print item
```

I was expecting the output to be

> 192.168.2.1
>
> 192.168.2.2
>
> 192.168.2.6

But I'm not getting the desired output. The output is just one item which looks like this:

> ('192.168.2.1', '\nHost is up (0.023s latency).\nPORT     STATE  SERVICE\n5001/tcp closed commplex-link\nMAC Address: EC:1A:59:A2:84:80 (Belkin International)\n\nNmap scan report for 192.168.2.2\nHost is up (0.053s latency).\nPORT     STATE  SERVICE\n5001/tcp closed commplex-link\nMAC Address: 94:35:0A:F0:47:C2 (Samsung Electronics Co.)\n\nNmap scan report for 192.168.2.3\nHost is up (0.18s latency).\nPORT     STATE    SERVICE\n5001/tcp filtered commplex-link\nMAC Address: 00:13:CE:C0:E5:F3 (Intel Corporate)\n\nNmap scan report for 192.168.2.6\nHost is up (0.062s latency).\nPORT     STATE  SERVICE\n5001/tcp )

Where am I going wrong?

Solution:
Below logic worked for me. If anyone has a better answer,  please let me know.

```
fp = open('nmap_op.txt').read()
entries = re.split('\n\n',fp)  
ip = re.compile('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*?closed',re.S)
matched = []
for item in entries:
  if ip.search(item):
    matched.append(ip.search(item).group(1))
```

Comment: +1 for included relevant code, expected output, and actual output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Below logic worked for me.

```
fp = open('nmap_op.txt').read()
entries = re.split('\n\n',fp)  
ip = re.compile('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*?closed',re.S)
matched = []
for item in entries:
  if ip.search(item):
    matched.append(ip.search(item).group(1))
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't need [`re.S`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.S) here. The `s` modifier changes the meaning of the dot meta-character (`.`) from "*match everything **except** newline characters*" to "*match everything **including** newline characters*". You don't need that here.

The second capturing group isn't required either. You can just remove it to have only the IPs returned:

```
>>> matched = re.findall('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*closed', fp)
>>> matched
['192.168.2.1', '192.168.2.2', '192.168.2.6']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amal. Actually the IP address and 5001/tcp closed are on different lines. I noticed that I had not given the text file format correctly. Sorry about that. I used a new pattern 
    ip = re.compile('([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+).*?closed',re.S)
with this I get output as 
    ['192.168.2.1', '192.168.2.2','192.168.2.3']
The last entry is incorrect and I think even you understand why. I'm getting close. I just need a pattern which will ignore the IP if it sees a pattern as 'filtered' in between. Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Since the lines format seems to be always the same (the ip starts at offset 21 and ends at the next space), you can try this another way without regex:

```
for block in data.split("\n\n"):
    if block.find('5001/tcp closed')>0:
        print block[21:block.find('\n', 27)]
```

Comment: Hey Casimir. Thanks for your answer. Actually the IP address and 5001/tcp closed are on different lines. I noticed that I had not given the text file format correctly. Sorry about that. I have corrected the text file format. I liked your idea though. I'm thinking on this line as well

Comment: @Sanket: I see, it doesn't matter, I'm sure there is a more efficient way than using a regex for you specific case, since your data are clearly formated (or at least a more simple pattern)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^Nmap.*?(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+).*?5001\/tcp closed', fp, re.M)
# ['192.168.2.1', '192.168.2.2', '192.168.2.6']
```